# Convert files names into integers

Tags: linux

So I have:

01.jpg
02.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
05.jpg

and want to make them all like below using a shell script or a command on linux

1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
5.jpg

Comment: Are you likely to have *both* 06.jpg and 6.jpg, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the command `rename` on your system,

```
rename "s/0(\\d+\\.jpg)/\$1/" *.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in 0*.jpg; do
    mv $i ${i:1}
done
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove *any* number of zeros from the start and prevent collisions:

```
for old in 0*.jpg; do
    new=$(echo ${old} | sed 's/^00*//')
    if [[ ! -f ${new} ]] ;then
        mv ${old} ${new}
    else
        echo "${old} conflicts with ${new}"
    fi
done
```

Of course, `rename` is a better option if available. I'm just including this for completeness in case you're running on a UNIX box that doesn't have that tool.